# How to use different css for different languages in dnn?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I'm using a dnn portal with two languages,English and Persian,in my Persian portal text direction is rtl and aligned right, when I change language to English,text align correctly change, but there is no change in menu bar and it still remain as right aligned, how can I use different css for each of my languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after creating a copy of skin.css do that

in your site root file Default.aspx.cs replace

```
ClientResourceManager.RegisterStyleSheet(this, ctlSkin.SkinPath + "skin.css", FileOrder.Css.SkinCss);
```

with

```
if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name == "en-US")
{
    ClientResourceManager.RegisterStyleSheet(this, ctlSkin.SkinPath + "skin.css", FileOrder.Css.SkinCss);
}
else
{
    ClientResourceManager.RegisterStyleSheet(this, ctlSkin.SkinPath + "arabicskin.css", FileOrder.Css.SkinCss);
}
```